# Cannot apply operator '==' to type 'System,.Nullabe<decimal>' and 'System.Nullable<double>' Error

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand why the following method below is throwing this error. I would appreciate it if some one would help or point me in the right direction.

```
 public List<Data> GetResults(string manufacturer, int? vehicle, double? engine )
        {
var results =c ontext.Data.Where(x => x.Name == manufacturer)
                        .Where(x => x.ModelId == model)
                        .Where(x => x.EngineLitreCapacity == engine) // <<  error occurs on this line!
                        .GroupBy(x => x.EngineLitreCapacity)
                        .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ToList();

        }
```

What am i doing doing wrong and how would i go about in resolving my query above? 
Thank you

Comment: Tell me first, what do you understand about the error that you are getting? What does it mean to you?

Comment: The error message says everything you need, there is no `==` operator that can compare `Nullable<Decimal>` and `Nullable<Double>`. You will have to convert/cast one to the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EngineLitreCapacity` seems to be a `decimal?` while your `engine` is a `double?`. Those variables are not comparable without casting.

The easy solution is to make `engine` a `decimal?`. That might cause casting issues later on, which you have to resolve. It is definitely a bad idea to just cast the `double?` since its precision might cause the equation to fail anyways.